# split the digits/ show the summation

Tags: split, sum, addition, digits

---

This is my code so far but when I run sum_of_digits("45ggd") I am getting the below result:

The sum of digits is 9 .

The extracted non-digits are:         ['ggd']

9

As i would like it to be:

The sum of digits is 4 + 5 .

The extracted non-digits are: ['g', 'g', 'd']
9

```
def sum_of_digits(string):

    sum_digits = 0
    extracted_alphas = ""

    for char in string:
        if char.isdigit() == True:
            sum_digits += int(char)
    
        elif char.isalpha():
            extracted_alphas += char
          
    else:
        if (len(string)==0):
            sum_digits = "" 
            print("Empty string entered!")     
            return 0 

        elif char.isdigit() == False:
            print("The sum of digits operation could not detect a digit!")
            print("The returned input letters are: ['" + str(extracted_alphas) + "']")
            return 0

    print("The sum of digits is", sum_digits,".")
    print("The extracted non-digits are: ['" + str(extracted_alphas) + "']")
    return sum_digits
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the sum of digits as an expression (like 4+5), you need to build a string using the digits of the given string. To print the alphabets present in the specified format, you need to store them in a list.

```py
def sum_of_digits(string):

    sum_digits = ""
    extracted_alphas = []
    
    if (len(string)==0):
        sum_digits = "" 
        print("Empty string entered!")     
        return 0

    for char in string:
        if char.isdigit() == True:
            sum_digits += char+"+"
    
        elif char.isalpha():
            extracted_alphas.append(char)

    if len(sum_digits) == 0:
        print("The sum of digits operation could not detect a digit!")
        print("The returned input letters are: ", extracted_alphas)
        return 0
    
    sum_digits = sum_digits[:-1]
    print("The sum of digits is", sum_digits,".")
    print("The extracted non-digits are: ", extracted_alphas)
    return sum_digits
```